# How to get an object value inside another object by a property value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an object like this

```
const test = { 
        '/blogs/architecture': 
            {
                name: 'Architecture',
                icon: 'archway',
                iconCategory: 'fas',
                slug: '/blogs/architecture'
            }
         }
```

Now I want find the slug field and I have only the name field. How can I find the slug by the name? please help

Comment: If you have  `name = "Architecture"` then you can use **test[`/blogs/${name.toLowerCase()}`].slug**.

Comment: if the name is in two word like 'design ideas' and the object keys '/blogs/design-ideas' then what can I do

Comment: then you can use `test[/blogs/${name.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}].slug`

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) with [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const test = {
    '/blogs/architecture': {
        name: 'Architecture',
        icon: 'archway',
        iconCategory: 'fas',
        slug: '/blogs/architecture'
    }
};

const findSlugByName = name => {
    return Object.values(test).find(obj => obj.name === name)?.slug;
}

console.log(findSlugByName('Architecture'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = {
    '/blogs/architecture': {
        name: 'Architecture',
        icon: 'archway',
        iconCategory: 'fas',
        slug: '/blogs/architecture'
    },
    '/blogs/architecture2': {
        name: 'Architecture2',
        icon: 'archway',
        iconCategory: 'fas',
        slug: '/blogs/architecture'
    }
}
const searchName = 'Architecture';
let searchResult;

const node = Object.values(test).forEach((node) => {
    if(node.name === searchName) {
        searchResult = node;
    }
});

console.log(searchResult);
```